# FI-LAB:Object storage authentiaction

Tags: fiware, openstack-swift, filab

I have community account in Lannion2 node, they have working ObjectStorage GE implementation (at least it works via cloud menu).

The problem is I cannot access the ObjectStorage API beacause of authentication procedure. It seems the authentication API for ObjectStorage changed since [cloud](https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/) changed IDM  on May 2015.

Does anyone know how can I get a token to authorize my requests to ObjectStorage API?

The way described at FIWARE wiki doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process now is the same that you should follow in order to get a token from the Keystone. Just send a POST request to the corresponding URL:

http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v2.0/tokens

with your credentials in the payload

```
{"auth": {"passwordCredentials": {"username": "****", "password": "****"}}}
```

It should return information like the following:

```
{
  "access": {
      "token": {
          "issued_at": "2015-05-29T08:42:35.095682", 
          "expires": "2015-05-30T08:42:35Z", 
          "id": "*****", 
          ...
       }
   }
}
```

The token id (access.token.id) is the data that you have to use in order to send any request, putting this value in the X-Auth-Token

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm getting the token properly. I include a X-Auth-Token header and make a get request for https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/Lannion2/object-store/v1/AUTH_0000000000000000000000000000xxxxx,  I response i'm receiving : <html>
    <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
    <p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.</p>
</html>

Comment: Furthermore, when I look into how requests look in case of cloud access (i'm checking it in browser console) to ObjectStorage it is different from one you've posted, the auth apparently uses keystone v3 api to authenticate. Did you checked method you proposed?

Comment: You can use both of them, I personally use v2.0 due to I had it saved in a Rest Client application. I am sure that it is working I check it again today. Try to check it again, yesterday there was a problem with the IdM.

Comment: is this endpoint "http://cloud.lab.fiware.org:4730/v2.0/tokens" still working?  I always get "503 Service Unavailable"

Comment: Yes, it is work, nevertheless if you detect any problem in some of the services the best way to resolve it or that we can attend it is sending a message to the email <fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org> there is a team behind it to attend the incidences in the platform.